# OracleDataAdapter CommandText for Updating Dataset

Tags: c#, database, datagrid, odp.net

I'm using grids in my project those are filled via `DataSet`s and `DataTable`s.
I use `DataNavigator`s on `grid`s for inserting, deleting and updating rows and i want to commit the changes to `database` via `OracleDataAdapter`.`Update`.
How should i set the `CommandText` of `OracleDataAdapter` for `update`, `delete` and `insert` while there is only one `CommandText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fill the DataTable using the OracleDataAdapter you keep the adapter in a global variable that you can reuse when it is time to update the datatable on the backend database. This adapter could be linked to an object of class [OracleCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommandbuilder.aspx) that (as the name explains) builds for you the UpdateCommand, InsertCommand and DeleteCommand properties of the Adapter.

When you call the Update method of the Adapter these commands are used to execute the sql instructions to update your table.

```
OracleDataAdapter _dataAdapter = null;

public void FillDataGridView(string conString, string selectCmd, string tableName)
{
   using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString))
   {
       _dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
       _dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(selectCmd, con);
       OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(_dataAdapter);
       con.Open();
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       _adapter.Fill(ds, tableName);
       dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   }
}
```

Then when you decide to update

```
// The OracleCommandBuilder has initialized the Insert/Update/Delete 
// command of the adapter thus the Update works as expected
DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
_adapter.Update(dt);
```

There are limits to what the CommandBuilder could do for you. In particular if the select command doesn't retrieve the primary key of the table or if the select command joins tables together then the CommandBuilder cannot create the relative commands and you need to define them manually

Comment: I created OracleDataAdapter as member variable one for each grid in UserControl that has the grids. The thing is encapsulation suffers from this. i have to include Oracle.DataAccess.dll in my GUI project that has UserControls(normally it was included only in my DB Project) Is there a better practice for this?

Comment: Well, If I understand correctly you have a UI layer and a DB layer. Something between the two is missing, a business layer where your UI asks for data presented in a logical view (IEnumerable<T>), so in this design a certain level of coupling is practically impossible to avoid. However is not easy to give a better practice without knowing the details of your project. You could pass the grid to fill to the DB layer, but this will only invert the coupling

Comment: Actually the project gets data from DB presents it to user and users can update data from GUI to DB. Almost all business logic part of it is in PlSql. So i'm calling plsql procedures and there is not an obvious business logic beside that. So i didn't create an extra business layer because it's handled in db. May be i can encapsulate PLSql procedures in a separate business logic part. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, adding a level of indirection between the UI and DB (when it doesn't slow down to much the response time) is a good move

Comment: I get "virtual column not allowed here" exception when i call update command with an insert. it says it may be because of a view but i don't use a view  as a cause. My select query is as plain as "select t.* ,t.rowid from interline_agreement t". Do you have any suggestion what may the cause be?

Comment: Some columns of sequence type or some readonly? (rowid) Just guessing here now